# How to add color array to mesh in meshio?

Tags: python, graphics, mesh, meshio

```
############points (108 ea)##################
[[362. 437.   0.]
 [418. 124.   0.]
 [452.  64.   0.]
...
 [256. 512.   0.]
 [  0. 256.   0.]
 [512. 256.   0.]]
##########triangles (205 ea)#################
[[ 86 106 100]
 [104  95 100]
 [ 41 104 101]
...
 [  0  84  36]
 [ 84   6  36]
 [  6  84   0]]
################triangle_colours (205 ea)##############
[[0.69140625 0.2734375  0.3203125  1.        ]
 [0.8046875  0.37109375 0.36328125 1.        ]
 [0.83203125 0.48046875 0.40234375 1.        ]
...
 [0.46875    0.13671875 0.26171875 1.        ]
 [0.49609375 0.1796875  0.28515625 1.        ]
 [0.91796875 0.796875   0.71484375 1.        ]]
```

Code:

```
 import meshio


    cells = [
        ("triangle", triangles) 
    ]  
    
    mesh = meshio.Mesh(
        points,
        cells, 
        cell_data={"a": triangle_colours},
    )
    mesh.write(
        "foo.vtk", 
    )
```

Above code gives

```
ValueError: Incompatible cell data. 1 cell blocks, but 'a' has 205 blocks.
```

I just want to add colors to triangles. triangle_colours array has the same size as triangles as per the example in here:  https://github.com/nschloe/meshio .(Both has 205 elements) How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell_data` corresponds to `cells`, so it needs to have the same "blocked" structure.

```py
import meshio


cells = [("triangle", triangles)]
    
mesh = meshio.Mesh(
    points,
    cells, 
    cell_data={"a": [triangle_colours]},
)
mesh.write("foo.vtk")
```